# When I try to calculate the subnet, I found subnet is exceed the range 0-255

Tags: ipv4, subnet

Consider a router that interconnects four subnets: Subnet 1, Subnet
2, Subnet 3 and Subnet 4. Suppose all of the interfaces in each of
these four subnets are required to have the prefix 195.200.0.0/23 (i.e.,
a /23 CIDR portion of the IP space is provided).

Also suppose thatSubnet 1 is required to support 100 interfaces, 
Subnet 2 is required tosupport 110 interfaces, 
Subnet 3 is required to support 60 interfaces and 
Subnet 4 is required to support 80 interfaces.

when I try to set the subnet 4, the IP is exceed the 255 should I write into 195.200.1.X or 
just write there is an error?

Thanks

Comment: Could you also include the codes that you wrote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv4's dotted decimal notation is just a way of writing a 32-bit number.

```
Dotted decimal: 195.     200.     0.       1
Hex:            C3       C8       00       01
Binary:         11000011 11001000 00000000 00000001
```

A /23 means the first 23 bits are the network and subnet identifiers, and the remaining 9 bits are for the host.

```
Binary:         11000011 11001000 00000000 00000001
                                         ^--------^
                                       Host identifier
```

So you can assign hosts addresses from:

```
Binary:         11000011 11001000 00000000 00000001
```

To:

```
Binary:         11000011 11001000 00000001 11111110
```

(The first and last addresses, `0 00000000` and `1 11111111`, are special.)

Turn this back into IPv4's dotted decimal notation, and you get:

```
Dotted decimal: 195.     200.     1.       254
Binary:         11000011 11001000 00000001 11111110
```

So you can use addresses in the range 195.200.0.1 to 195.200.1.254

Comment: I got it, Thank you so much